# Can't load data in Excel after exporting from JSP

Tags: java, excel, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I try to export file the error is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "loadltklSubmitInfo"`
This is my JSP for making Excel file:

```
<tr>
    <th>Nama File Zip</th>
    <th>Jumlah Data LTKL Terkirim</th>
    <th>Jumlah Data LTKL Terproses</th>
    <th>Jumlah Data LTKL Sukses</th>
    <th>Tanggal Kirim</th>
    <th>Tanggal Terima</th>         
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${data.loadltklSubmitInfo}" var="ltklSubmit">        
    <td><c:out value="${ltklSubmit.zipFileName}" /> </td>
    <td><c:out value="${ltklSubmit.ltklCount}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${ltklSubmit.ltklCountProcess}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${ltklSubmit.ltklCountSuccess}" /></td>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${ltklSubmit.sentDate}" pattern='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'/></td>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${ltklSubmit.receiveDate}" pattern='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'/></td>

</c:forEach>
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping ("/cekSubmitExport.htm")
public ModelAndView loadExportExcelLTKL (HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-Cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 1);

    //String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String file = request.getParameter("zipFileName");


    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("cekSubmitExportView");

    //if (type.equals("1"))
    //{
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=HasilSubmitLTKL.xls");
        //view.addObject("flag", "1");
        view.addObject("data", exportExcelService.getltklSubmitInfoByFile(file));
```

this is my service:

```
@Autowired
private LtklSubmitInfoDao ltklSubmitInfoDao;


@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public List<LtklSubmitInfo> getltklSubmitInfoByFile(String zipFileName)
{
    return ltklSubmitInfoDao.loadAll(zipFileName);
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace, if available. NumberFormatException is usually thrown by a "parse" method when the input string does not represent a number. e.g. if you invoke something like `Integer.parseInt("notANumber")` instead of `Integer.parseInt("1234")`.

Comment: this is the full stack trace,
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "loadltklSubmitInfo"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)
at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
t org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)